# Excel Match, Index VLOOKUP Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to populate a cell, and only display value if it does not already exist. If it exists, then display another value.

...But I cannot get my head around how to do this.

I currently have the following formula placed on cells in the E column

```
=INDEX(config!H2:H20,
MATCH(1,
(F4=config!F2:F20)*(VLOOKUP(D4,config!C2:D20,2,FALSE)=config!G2:G20),0))
```

This matches some other criteria as you can see here. However, what you can also see is the value 7 is getting displayed twice. I'm wanting it not to display any values in use.

[image]
So, I then added an extra column, called 'Room In Use' in a config sheet, where the data is coming from... this column has some formulas to check if the values are in use

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(H2,Sheet1!E2:E41,0)))
```

You can see this in action here: [image]

So, going back to my sheet1, I think this formula needs another condition to say If **room in use** == FALSE then do

```
=INDEX(config!H2:H20,
MATCH(1,
(F4=config!F2:F20)*(VLOOKUP(D4,config!C2:D20,2,FALSE)=config!G2:G20),0))
```

else if all rooms are TRUE then display 'None Available'

I tried using:

```
{=INDEX(config!H2:H20,MATCH(1,(F5=config!F2:F20)*("FALSE"=config!J2:J20)*(VLOOKUP(D5,config!C2:D20,2,FALSE)=config!G2:G20),0)) }
```

but to no avail...

Is this even possible in an excel formula or will I need to use VBA?

I have attached my excel document here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/crmbbp8esdvnv29/Book1.xlsm?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the *first, second, third, etc* matches, you need to switch to a SMALL(IF(... or AGGREGATE to return the matching row numbers to INDEX where the *k* argument is provided by a progressive  COUNTIF or COUNTIFS of already used values on the local worksheet.

While a<s>n overly complicated</s> single formula may be ultimately possible, your use of the double lookup matching column D to config!C:C to return a value in config!D:D could use a 'helper' column to ease the conditional count.

Put this formula into M2 (optionally use a custom number format of `;;;`) then drag down through M2:M20.

```
=VLOOKUP(D2, config!C:D, 2, FALSE)&F2
```

The formula in E2:E20 is now,

```
=INDEX(config!H:H,
       AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($2:$20)/((config!F$2:F$20=F2)*(config!G$2:G$20=VLOOKUP(D2, config!C:D, 2, FALSE))), 
       COUNTIF(M$2:M2, VLOOKUP(D2, config!C:D, 2, FALSE)&F2)))
```

Don't be surprised to receive an error in E16. This will be rectified once you fix the typo in D16. All other #NUM! errors occur when you run out of possible matching values.

Comment: Hey, this is really clever solution that I would not have came up with... Some cells come back with the following error #NUM https://i.imgur.com/VI5zNBq.png - is this because no values left?

Comment: Yes. Mary is a #NUM! because she is the third *YesYes* and there are only two on the config worksheet. You've simply run out of matching possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, it's very much appreciated.